# In R, how can I combine two columns within a data.frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm working with some data that looks like this:

```
AB 123 4 5 3 2 1
AB 234 4 2 7 4 3 
...
```

The row id is actually the combination of the first two columns, so I would like to be able to reference row AB123 or AB234. However, since they are in two columns, I figured the easiest way to do this would be to merge columns 1 and 2 somehow and then convert it to a table with column 1 specified as the row names. Does anyone know how I can do this? Is there an easier way? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
row.names(df)<-paste(df[,1],df[,2],sep="")
```